# cordova-plugin-fcm doesn't work on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am using cordova-plugin-fcm in an ionic project to use Firebase push notification.
The Notification is working fine for android platform, but when I added iOS platform I couldn't get any notification on my device.

Here are the things I've done:
1- I added GoogleService-Info.plist to my project and inside platforms in ios folder.
2- Enabled notification from xCode 
3- I also tried to send test notification from Firebase console and it worked.
4- The back-end team fired the function that sends notification and I could received the notification on my device.

But when I test the app and try the case where notification should be received, I never get it.

I don't even know how to debug this issues. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Asmaa, did you already try to send a notification from the Firebase console directly? I have a similar issue (SO question open), also from the console it is not working and it fails with 'unregistered token'.

Comment: Hi, Yes I tried to send notification from the firebase console and I recieved the notification on my ios device. I didn't kniw how to debug on ios so I will try remote debuging on safiri and see what I will get

Comment: @AsmaaAmrawy You are saying that you receive the notification when you use Firebase but not from server. If that is the case then check that proper(development or distribution) .p12 file has been added in firebase and also check the server key.

Comment: @PriyankGujarati No I am recieving notification when I use firebase and from server but not when I use the app.

Comment: @AsmaaAmrawy So you need to add the **server key** to the backend side.

Comment: Hi guys, it turned out to be a back-end issue not an issue in the plugin itself.
The issue in the back-end was a wrong if condition.

Answer (score 0):

it turned out to be a back-end issue not an issue in the plugin itself.
The issue in the back-end was a wrong if condition.